# Auto-sizing a parent div

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to put a child image, with its size adjusted, inside a parent div. How do I get this parent div's with to be the same, and not bigger, than the child image? See the below snipppet for an example. Thanks.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @Rob What the OP has made is XHTML safe... It's totally fine and more right way...

Comment: @PraveenKumar I would wager money he's not using, and never will use, XHTML. But the question is tagged HTML

Comment: @Rob I agree with you, but I love to use XHTML instead of HTML... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why in the world would you use XHTML in a HTML document? Google "tag soup".

Comment: @Rob Umm... Sure... Lemme check. **Update:** Nice one man... Looks good. Learnt something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using a percentage for the img size is the problem. You are saying that your image has to be 80% of the parent div therefore you are explicitly telling the img not to fill the whole div.
The other problem you have is that an image is an inline element, if you change that to block it will remove the extra space at the bottom of the image.

See the CSS

```
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Also a [Pen](https://codepen.io/fabioioio/pen/QOvjoW)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you need to have the `width` of the `img` to be `100%` and have the `width` or something of `80%`:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png" />
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks, however, changing the size of the parent div instead does not change the size of the child image, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hgk4Lme9/32/).